# elasticsearch errors when trying ping

Tags: elasticsearch

I try the following code:

```
def connect ():
        es = None
        es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
        print(es.ping())
```

and I get the following errors:

```
/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/venv/bin/python /Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/scratch.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/scratch.py", line 7, in <module>
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/__init__.py", line 333, in __init__
    node_configs = client_node_configs(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py", line 105, in client_node_configs
    node_configs = hosts_to_node_configs(hosts)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py", line 154, in hosts_to_node_configs
    node_configs.append(host_mapping_to_node_config(host))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/practical_week4_ex_1/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/utils.py", line 221, in host_mapping_to_node_config
    return NodeConfig(**options)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: NodeConfig.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'scheme'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

some form of response, no errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using relatively recent version of the python client. Is it 8.x? If this is the case you are missing an `scheme` parameter that should be either 'http' or 'https` depending on how you installed elasticsearch. So, it should be something like this if you disabled ssl and authentication on your local installation.

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'scheme': 'http', 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
```

However, if you did a default install. You are probably using self-generated SSL keys and some autogenerated credentials. So you would need to disable SSL authentication and suppress warnings, which is not recommended on a real installation, but should be ok for your local testing:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'scheme': 'https', 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], 
    basic_auth=('username', 'password'), 
    verify_certs=False, 
    ssl_show_warn=False
)
```

A proper solution should be to point your client to the generated CA certificates:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'scheme': 'https', 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], 
    basic_auth=('username', 'password'), 
    ca_certs='<Path to elastic home>/config/certs/http_ca.crt',
)
```